# Laravel - Returning an Eloquent Instance Syntax

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So I have a controller with a constructor that uses Reflection to inject a Eloquent Model dependency:

```
public function __construct(Analysis $analysis)
{
    $this->analysis = $analysis;
}
```

This dependency also has other Eloquent Model dependencies that are injected via Reflection:

```
use App\Load;
use App\Parameter;

class Analysis extends Model
{
    protected $loads;
    protected $parameters;

    public function __construct(Load $loads, Parameter $parameters)
    {
        $this->loads = $loads;
        $this->parameters = $parameters;
    }
}
```

When I dump or die like so:

```
dd($this->analysis['loads']);
```

It returns Load as an Eloquent instance (as I would like it to).

But then when I try dump or die like so:

```
dd($this->analysis->loads);
```

It just returns an empty collection. I can't figure out why one works and not the other? I've seen the latter syntax work in tutorial videos.

I wasn't sure what to put in the post title because I don't know the terms of the differing syntax (analysis['loads'] vs analysis->loads).

Comment: The first method depicts that your Eloquent instance is of type "Array"whereas the second one depicts​ that your Eloquent instance is of type "Object"

Comment: Did you define a relationship between Analysis model and Load model.

Comment: What are you passing to the constructor of your model? ...and why?

Comment: @KelvinC yes, Load belongs to  Analysis, and Analysi has many Loads.

Comment: @nikhil_gandhi Thanks for the response, your answer has given me a clue to the error...

Comment: @RossWilson they are Eloquent models that are resolved using Reflection

Answer (score 0):

So changing the loads & parameters properties to `public` meant that

```
dd($this->analysis->loads);
```

Would then return an Eloquent instance, as desired. Probably not the best solution. I guess the correct way would be to use getters and setters...